# How can I get the type of an event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I want to know the type of e when CheckedChanged event is fired. c#

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: can you explain why you want to get that type

Comment: Should the state of your checkbox be evaluated? What is your goal?

Comment: I just need to know what's the Type of EventArgs e, the moment I handle the CheckedChanged event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every object in .net have method `GetType()` to get type of it i.e method of the base class object which is get inherited by every type.

so to get the type of the event you can use 
`e.GetType()` method will give you type of your event.

Answer (score 0):

Set an breakpoint at the event and quick watch e. The Type should be displayed